# PHP arrray and string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have problems with arrays. When I try to get the first array [0] it does not give me anything.
This is output

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [333]=> string(123) "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hl-cdn-prod60/f/de/d6/fded6f1587f863a9e8fc1c2173143a8782fa655e/700Wx700H-105395-0416.jpg" [334]=> string(125) "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hl-cdn-prod60/e/b9/54/eb954216442547d2ed2c71adbcf73d4f2b3ef903/700Wx700H-105395-a-0416.jpg" [335]=> string(125) "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/hl-cdn-prod60/7/16/95/71695917dd17d29648c8f4907000e3c6cab64581/700Wx700H-105395-b-0416.jpg" }
```

and this is code

```
private function getImages($dom) {

        $images = [];

        foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('ul') as $ul) {
            if ($ul->getAttribute('class') == 'image-thumbnails') {
                foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('li') as $li) {
                    $images[] = $li->getAttribute('data-zoom-url');
                }
            }
        }

        $images = array_unique($images);

        return $images;
    }
```

Comment: What is the input data? ie, what is in the $dom-variable?

Comment: What do you mean with "it doesn't give me anything"? That nothing is printed on the display? Because the array is actually giving you back something when you ask for the first element: an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude empty values, check if the attribute is empty before adding it to the array:

```
if(!empty($li->getAttribute('data-zoom-url'))) {
   $images[] = $li->getAttribute('data-zoom-url');
}
```